# Can we make a button focusable in a table caption for Mac Firefox using Tab key press

Tags: firefox, accessibility

I have a table with caption, and there is some information which will be shown when info icon is clicked.

When I am checking if it is accessible by tab press in Mac Google Chrome, It worked fine.
But when I try the same in mac Firefox, I am not able to go to the button.

Created a sample Codepen with the usecase.
I would like to know, if it is feasible to make button in table caption accessible by tab key press in Firefox.

code pen link: https://codepen.io/sivachaitanyaa-backflipt-com/pen/qBvyEJr?editors=1010

```
<h1>Tables with captions</h1>
<h2>Default</h2>
<p>You can style the caption as you would any other text element.</p>
<table>
    <caption>Source details table for Research Question 1
        <button tabindex=0>
            Click for more info
        </button>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Question 1 Source details: website</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Author(s)/Organisation/Publisher</td>
            <td>D Fox</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name of website</td>
            <td>stylus</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name of webpage</td>
            <td>Adding captions to tables in HTML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date created/updated</td>
            <td>8 October 2020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date accessed</td>
            <td>9 October 2020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.stylus.co.za/adding-captions-to-tables-in-html/" target="_blank">http://www.stylus.co.za/adding-captions-to-tables-in-html</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Bottom</h2>
<table>
    <caption style="caption-side: bottom; text-align: right;">Source details table for Research Question 2</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Question 2 Source details: website</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Author(s)/Organisation/Publisher</td>
            <td>w3schools.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name of website</td>
            <td>w3schools.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name of webpage</td>
            <td>HTML &lt;caption&gt; Tag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date created/updated</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date accessed</td>
            <td>9 October 2020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp" target="_blank">https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Alignment</h2>
<table>
    <caption style="text-align: right;">Source details table for Research Question 3</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Question 3 Source details: PDF</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td>F Avrakotos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Computer Applications Technology Theory Concepts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date published</td>
            <td>April 2018</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just tested with a link `<a>` inside the `<caption>` and also Firefox on Windows does not seem to include the elements in the tab order (I guess you can remove the Mac part from your question). Both elements are correctly exposed to the accessibility tree, and with the NVDA screen reader it’s possible to interact with them.

Comment: If you would describe what you are trying to achieve with this rather unconventional solution, we might be able to suggest an alternative that works (:

Answer (score 0):

This is a known and still open [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=242829) from 11 years ago. Unfortunately a fix seems complicated.

So the answer is no, we cannot.

Interactive elements inside a `<caption>` cannot be tabbed to, but they are correctly exposed to assistive technology. The bug report does not mention a workaround.

> The caption element represents the title of the table that is its parent, if it has a parent and that is a table element.

Adding interactive elements to a parent that provides an accessible name seems like a misuse.

So my advice would be to find another solution for your use case, one which is more common.